# Trying to use echo’s commas instead of string concatenation

Tags: php, concatenation

I don't know what I'm doing wrong here, but I'm getting parse error:
 "**Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ',' in...**"

```
$msg= 'This is ', htmlentities($from, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'),' and ', htmlentities($to, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'),' dates statistic ';
echo $msg;
```

Can you help me? I don't want to use concatenation, because of slower speed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `,` between the strings by `.` in the $msg:

```
$msg= 'This is ' . htmlentities($from, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8') . ' and ' . 
      htmlentities($to, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8') . ' dates statistic ';
```

or echo directly:

```
echo 'This is ', htmlentities($from, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'),' and ', htmlentities($to, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'),' dates statistic ';
```

Answer (score 3):

Basicaly commas seperated values are arguments. You are trying to pass arguments to the variable but not echo!

```
echo 'This is ',
  htmlentities($from, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'),
  ' and ',
  htmlentities($to, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'),
  ' dates statistic ';
```

Answer (score 2):

echo accepts multiple values separted with commas, variable assignation does not.

that will work

```
echo 'This is ', htmlentities($from, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'),' and ', htmlentities($to, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'),' dates statistic ';
```

or

```
$msg= 'This is '. htmlentities($from, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8') . ' and ' . htmlentities($to, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8') . ' dates statistic ';
echo $msg;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't use the commas in the string assignment, the commas only work for the `echo` command itself. So if you want to avoid concatenation as you mentioned above you need to do this:

```
echo  'This is ', htmlentities($from, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'),
      ' and ', htmlentities($to, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'),' dates statistic ';
```

Answer (score 1):

```
echo 'This is ', htmlentities($from, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'),' and ', htmlentities($to, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'),' dates statistic ';
```

The commas only work with `echo`, not with variable assignment.